# SQL Server query improve performance on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select, sql-like

How can I improve the next [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) query?

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) 
FROM Products
WHERE Type = 'SODA'
AND (Code LIKE 'A5%'
OR Code IN('DHA2','JHU8','KML2','LQA1','ZSX2'))
```

Takes a lot of time in execution.

Thanks in advance.

I'm getting data from a DB2 database through Linked Server. I can't build indexes just read.

```
Id   int
Name nvarchar(100)
Type nvarchar(100)
Code nvarchar(100)
Qty  int
```

Comment: what is your table schema (column types, indexes)?

Comment: are Type and Code indexed?

Comment: Is there an index on the column Code? If not, the Like operator will force a serial read. Creating an Explain Plan will help determine where the performance issue is.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan along with any indexes you already have. For what it's worth if you run this query in SQL Server Management Studio with the option "Include Actual Execution plan" enabled, SQL Server will suggest indexes that will improve your query. This is probably going to be far more useful than any answer given here, since we do not know anything about your table, just that it contains at least 3 columns (Qty, Type and Code).

Comment: The probable answer is create the following index `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Products_Code ON Products (Code) INCLUDE (Qty) WHERE Type = 'SODA'` - However that index is geared entirely towards this query, and probably not much help on your other queries.

Comment: How many rows are in the table?  If you can't build indexes, it's going to have to do a sequential scan on the entire table and that's simply going to be slow no matter what.

Answer (score 5):

First, try creating an index on `products(type, code, qty)`.  That might greatly improve performance.

Then, if that doesn't work, try rewriting the query as:

```
select sum(qty)
from ((select qty
       from products
       where type = 'SODA' and
             code like 'A5%'
      ) union all
      (select qty
       from products
       where type = 'SODA' and
             code IN ('DHA2','JHU8','KML2','LQA1','ZSX2'))
      )
     ) t;
```

This may look more complicated but sometimes `or` interferes with query optimization.

Comment: The person who asked stated that he cannot create indexes. So this is not the right answer because splitting the query into two queries on a table without indexes will cause two complete table scans instead of one. So the query will perform even slower.

Comment: @Baltico . . . If you look at the edit history, you will see that this comment was inserted into the question *after* this answer was completed.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I did not know that was possible. Of course without that restriction adding indexes will be the best advice.

Answer (score 3):

This is a linked server query.  You don't state how you're executing it so I'm assuming it is using the linked server name in the FROM.  If you look at the query plan, all you will see is Remote Query -->  Computer Scalar --> Select.  That basically means all of the data you are wanting to compute is copied into tempDB then calculated.

If you do the query as an EXEC at or OPENQUERY the query is executed remotely then the only thing to return is the result.

Try this:

```
select *
from 
openquery(LinkedServerName, '   
SELECT SUM(Qty) Total
FROM Products
WHERE Type = ''SODA''
AND (Code LIKE ''A5%''
OR Code IN(''DHA2'',''JHU8'',''KML2'',''LQA1'',''ZSX2'')) ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you using a linked server and also you are string comparisons, I am pretty sure your slow performance is because SQL Server has to bring the whole Product table from the DB2 database to a local copy, then compare the strings according to your current collation settings. You see, comparing strings may have different results on different collation settings, and on different database systems. When linking between Microsoft SQL Servers databases you can enable Collation compatibility so when the query is executed it will trust the linked server decision about string comparison and sorting. I don't know if collation compatibility is possible between Microsoft SQL Server and DB2. So the solution to the problem will be to use OPENROWSET instead of a linked server.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET 
 ('DB2OLEDB',Netlib=SNA;NetAddr=;NetPort=;RemoteLU=OLYMPIA;LocalLU=LOCAL;ModeName=QPCSUPP;User ID=WNW3XX;Password=WNW3XX;InitCat=OLYMPIA;Default Schema=WNW3XX;PkgCol=WNW3XX;TPName=;Commit=YES;IsoLvl=NC;AccMode=;CCSID=37;PCCodePage=1252;BinAsChar=NO;Data Source=Sample',
 'SELECT SUM(Qty) 
FROM Products
WHERE Type = ''SODA''
AND (Code LIKE ''A5%''
OR Code IN(''DHA2'',''JHU8'',''KML2'',''LQA1'',''ZSX2'')) ' )
```

See more info in [linked server to DB2 using Microsoft OLE DB provider for DB2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222937)

And in [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it takes that long, I suggest you create a table with the same structure, then build some helpful indexes, then execute your query against this local table:

```
DELETE FROM Products

INSERT INTO Products
SELECT * FROM RemoteServer.database_name..Products

SELECT SUM(Qty) 
FROM Products
WHERE Type = 'SODA'
AND (Code LIKE 'A5%'
OR Code IN('DHA2','JHU8','KML2','LQA1','ZSX2'))
```